# Question on inclusion and placement of Nishmat section in the Hagadda

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

We have nishmat through yistabach in the Hagadda right after the Great Hallel (Psalm 136).  Why are those specific paragraphs from the morning davening included, and why do they come immediately after the Great Hallel rather than long after (as in the morning davening)?

Comment: Try looking up ברכת השיר

Comment: @JoelK  I looked it up and do not see how that answers my question. Pls explain.

Comment: We say these paragraphs (along with Nishmat) as a (possible) fulfillment of the (possible) requirement to say Birkat Ha-Shir. No other paragraphs from the shacharit fit in to that context

Answer (score 4):

[Mishnah Pesachim 10:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.10.7?lang=bi):

> רְבִיעִי, גּוֹמֵר עָלָיו אֶת הַהַלֵּל, וְאוֹמֵר עָלָיו בִּרְכַּת הַשִּׁיר.‏
>
> On the fourth cup, one concludes the Hallel, and says over it 'the blessing of the song'.

[Talmud Bavli Pesachim 118a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.118a.1?lang=bi):

> מאי ברכת השיר רב יהודה אמר יהללוך ה׳ אלהינו ורבי יוחנן אמר נשמת כל חי תנו רבנן רביעי גומר עליו את ההלל ואומר הלל הגדול דברי רבי טרפון
>
> What is 'the blessing of the song'? Rav Yehudah says: "They will praise you Hashem our G-d". Rabbi Yochanan says: "The soul of every living thing".
>
> The Rabbis taught: On the fourth cup, one concludes the Hallel, and says the Great Hallel. These are the words of Rabbi Tarfon.

So, on Seder night, current common customs attempt to incorporate (as far as possible) the rulings of Rabbi Tarfon, Rabbi Yochanan and Rav Yehudah, reciting the Great Hallel after Hallel, and following this with the recitation of Nishmat and its concluding paragraphs, in deference to the opinion of Rabbi Yochanan.

(There are different customs regarding how and where to incorporate Rav Yehudah's ruling to recite Yehallelucha. There were (are?) also different customs regarding drinking a fifth cup in conjunction with reciting the Great Hallel.)

This is very different to *shacharit* on *shabbat* and holidays, where the recitations of these passages as part of *pesukei d'zimra* are described by Rambam ([Seder HaTefillot](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Order_of_Prayer.1.5?lang=bi)) as mere customs:

> בְּשַׁבָּת נָהֲגוּ כָּל הָעָם לְהוֹסִיף לִפְנֵי בְּרָכָה זוֹ נֹסַח זֶה. נִשְׁמַת כָּל חַי תְּבָרֵךְ אֶת שִׁמְךָ...וְיֵשׁ מְקוֹמוֹת שֶׁנָּהֲגוּ לִקְרוֹת הַלֵּל הַגָּדוֹל בְּשַׁבָּתוֹת קֹדֶם פְּסוּקֵי הַזְּמִירוֹת.‏
>
> On *shabbat* all the people are accustomed to add before this blessing [Yishtabach] the following passage: "The souls of all living things will bless Your Name..." And there are places where they have the custom to read the Great Hallel on *shabbatot* before *pesukei d'zimra*.

Comment: I think there's more to it than that. Take a look at https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.575.11?p2=Mishnah_Berurah.575.30&p3=Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.221.2

Comment: @Heshy Are you suggesting that nishmat is the concluding brachah for hallel hagadol? You might enjoy this article http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/hamaayan/amirat-2.htm

Comment: That's great!  Yeah, I was thinking something along those lines, but I hadn't developed it nearly as much as he did.

Comment: @Heshy It's a very nice piece, although, as Breuer admits at the end, somewhat speculative.